# Sybase 15.7 - is it worth upgrading?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

We are on Sybase 15.0.3

Sybase 15.7 seems to offer some useful things.

Above all we would like to know if it performs better or is worth taking on for other good reasons.

I hear that it runs a bit better on IBM SMT Power processors because it is multi-threading instead of peer unix processes.

There seems to be some IQ-like compression functionality, which sounds handy for very big tables with large row sizes.

I don't know if in-memory relaxed durability dbs would be useful to us however good they are as we'd have to do redesigns.  However - does anyone have any experience of these?

There is an MQ messaging bit that might be handy - anyone used that and got impressions?

We use all the new query optimiser things with v15.0 (hash and merge joins) so we're not expecting shocks or big differences there.

Is upgrading hard?  When we took on v15.0 we had to do a lot of testing, introduce login triggers and jobs to do more UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS.  However I am not expecting effort like that for v15.7.

Any opinions and information very gratefully received!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of usage you see in your current db, and what tasks it's tuned to accomplish.  Without some details, the best I can do is say 'yes, maybe'.

Comment: 20 engines, 90Gb memory approx.

Comment: Mixed app, mostly DSS, some OLTP.  Lots of parallel jobs doing logged del/ins/upd of small-ish sets of data (1000s of rows.)  Some multi-statement transactions but mostly just "DELETE last set, INSERT new set from #temptab" sort of things - these are all SPs using lots of #temptabs.  Also a lot of concurrent ETL loads of files into the system, most of which are 100s/few 1000 sets of rows, one or two many more, and quite a lot of big ETLs done with unlogged SELECT INTO with bcp-out at the end - these are all embedded (dynamic) sql in shell and perl.

Comment: Also lots of tempdbs - 8, with different types of job distributed appropriately.

Comment: Bear in mind the compression you mention in your post is an additional license cost (and isn't cheap) if you only have the basic licensing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your usage, you will likely benefit from upgrading.  Specifically, here are some of the improvement areas that may affect you.

- Query Processor latency has been reduced, espcially for dynamic sql.  Query plans may now also be shared across sessions.  Query excution engine performance has also been imporved.
- Kernel enhancements:  Better utilization of parallel cores, better use of I/O event processing with a reduction in I/O overhead, which should allow the better scaling.
- Ability to analyze query performance with dynamic parameters without running the queries.
- Merge (upserts)
- Fast Logged BCP
- Splitting/Merging/Moving data partitions improvements:  Should make managing partitioned data easier, and more effective
- Pre-computed result sets (materialized view):  Can improve performance with available result sets
- Hash based update statistics:  Allows a single table scan to update statistics.
- Enhanced Dump and Loading:  Header now includes necessary information to rebuild database, should create scripts be lost
- Async DB Initialization:  Database can be used instantly when created/altered.

As to the other parts of your question about specific features, I would roll over to the SAP Community Network forums for those questions.  Many SAP Sybase experts hang out over there.

http://scn.sap.com/community/sybase-ase-custom-applications

Comment: Thank you Michael - I was wondering whether you'd done upgrade(s) and got figures or impressions for how much better, whether worth it, etc.  I know that's a bit vague.  I also wonder how much trouble it is to do the upgrade.  I get the impression on the DBA side it's not that harrowing, and on the app side there is nothing tricky like for our v12 to v15.0 upgrade, when we did lots of testing for new optimisers and did login triggers and update index stats jobs.

Comment: I'm with Michael there are some performance issues with ULC unpin and some other behavior on 15.0.3 which was improved in 15.5 and later versions. What I will say is you may need to tune your thread pools if you use the threaded kernel model on ASE 15.7 depending upon how your current 20 engines are being used as query and IO tasks are on separate threads if you use threaded kernel mode.

There are also some serious bugs in ASE15.7 on some versions for spinlock on procedure cache which are fixed in ASE16 and can be tricky to diagnose without good MDA table monitoring so test thoroughly.